# 2D List not calculating properly

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm trying to do a game of life. There's this weird bug I can't really fix because I don't really know where the problem is? I'm guessing it's in the loop? I don't really know. I tried to debug it using the if total > 0 print(total), and the total is only 2 when it should've been 3. I'm sorry if i'm explaining it confusing because i'm also confused.

```
def test():
    board = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

    #Tracking the neighbor, it shows that there is 3 alive neighbors in 
    #here.
    print(board[2][1])
    print(board[2-1][1+1])
    print(board[2][1+1])
    print(board[2+1][1+1])

    return board

def update(grid, N):
    newGrid = grid.copy()
    for i in range(N):
        if i == 0 or i == 4:
            continue
        for j in range(N):
            if j == 0 or j == 4:
                continue
            total = 0
            total = total + grid[i][j-1] #
            total = total + grid[i][j+1] #
            total = total + grid[i-1][j] #
            total = total + grid[i+1][j] #
            total = total + grid[i-1][j-1] #
            total = total + grid[i-1][j+1] #
            total = total + grid[i+1][j-1] #
            total = total + grid[i+1][j+1] #

            # In here it only states that there's only 2 alive neighbors 
            # when there should've been 3
            if total > 0:
                print(total)

            # apply Conway's rules 
            if grid[i][j] == 1: 
                if (total < 2) or (total > 3): 
                    newGrid[i][j] = 0 
                elif total == 3:
                    newGrid[i][j] = 1
            else:
                if total == 3: 
                    newGrid[i][j] = 1

    grid[:] = newGrid[:]
    return(grid)

f = 0

zboard = test()
while f <= 3:
    print("Generation: " + str(f))
    gen = update(zboard, 5)
    for i in gen:
        print(i)
        f += 1
```

Comment: Can you specify what are your expected and actual outcomes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/copy.html).

When you do `newGrid = grid.copy()`, since you have a 2D-list, the sublists in `newGrid` will not be independent from the sublists from `grid`. Your problem was that `grid` was updated each time you updated `newGrid`.

You need to replace this:

```
newGrid = grid.copy()
```

by this :

```
import copy
newGrid = copy.deepcopy(grid)
```

Here is an example to show you what was happening. `cop_1` is a dependent copy whereas cop_2 is an independent one :

```
board = [[0, 0],
        [0, 0]]
cop_1 = board.copy()

import copy
cop_2 = copy.deepcopy(board)

board[0][0] = 3 # change a value of board

print("cop_1[0][0] =", cop_1[0][0])
# cop_1[0][0] = 3
print("cop_2[0][0] =", cop_2[0][0])
# cop_2[0][0] = 0
```

Comment: My pleasure. Just for you to know how I found the cause of your problem : I saw that the condition `if total == 3` was never reached, which was weird, and I saw that the values `1` in your board were updated to `0` during the for loop. And then I deduced you had dependent lists

Answer (score 0):

If you run the code like you posted, you get a mistake because you didn't indent the lines after your function `def test():` until `return board`

Comment: The indention in my file was correct, I'll edit the post